# Can I use a Let's Encrypt certificate with my self-hosted WCF application?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I've found several guides on how to generate a self-signed CA and then a cert for the service.

Example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service

I've little idea about certificates, so my question is, is the Let's Encrypt certificate compatible with a self-hosted WCF service?

I could buy a certificate, if a commercial CA offered a format that Let's Encrypt did not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use a Let's Encrypt certificate to make a WCF service communicate over https. You can set it up using one of the windows clients listed on the [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/) website.
If you decide to use the [ACMESharp client](https://github.com/ebekker/ACMESharp/wiki/Quick-Start), you will notice that one fundamental functionality is not yet implemented cleanly: [certificate renewal](https://github.com/ebekker/ACMESharp/issues/165).
However, this issue can be addressed by using a script provided by Marc Durdin he submitted [on his blog](https://marc.durdin.net/2017/02/lets-encrypt-on-windows-redux/).
After you have setup the ACMESharp client and defined the variables in the script, you will have to create a scheduled task which runs every 60 days and executes the script.

To make a WCF service use an https binding, you will have to define that binding in the configuration of the service.
Create a [`security`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element. Then, reference the parent `binding` elements' `name` attribute in the `bindingConfiguration` attribute of the [`endpoint` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731320%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In the `address` attribute of that same `endpoint` element you have to specify the https address under which your service will be available.
If you use a port different than 443, you will have to explicitly define it like so: `https://hostname.tld:port/ServiceName/`.

Once you have all this set up, you will have to bind the certificate supplied by letsencrypt to that binding. You can do this with the [`netsh http add sslcert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command. I wrote the following script which you can use to automate this process in conjunction with the renewal of the certificate mentioned above:

```
$domain = 'hostname.tld' # insert your hostname
$ipport = '0.0.0.0:portnumber' # insert the proper binding
$getThumb = Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My | where { $_.Subject -match $domain }
$certHash = $getThumb.Thumbprint
$activeBinding = netsh http show sslcert ipport=$ipport
$activeBindingHash = $activeBinding[5]
$guid = '{' + [guid]::NewGuid() + '}'
If( -Not $activeBindingHash )
{
    netsh http add sslcert ipport=$ipport certhash=$certHash appid=$guid  
    return  
}
$hashesMatch = $activeBindingHash | Select-String -Pattern $certHash -Quiet
If( -Not $hashesMatch )
{
    netsh http delete sslcert ipport=$ipport
    netsh http add sslcert ipport=$ipport certhash=$certHash appid=$guid    
}
```

If you define the variables in the script and run that as a scheduled task too, your wcf service will use an ssl certificate from Let's Encrypt which will get renewed and rebound automatically.